# Rust: How to send data from multiple channels via thread?

Tags: rust

Hello I am trying to send data received from unix datagram server to other function via multiple channels. I am connected to unix datagram server. Now I want to send received data with threads. Is it possible to send single data object to send to multiple channels? Here is the example code I am trying to resolve.

### example.rs

```
use std::os::unix::net::UnixDatagram;
use std::str::from_utf8;
use std::sync::mpsc::Sender;
use serde_json::Value;
use log::info;
use std::thread;


pub fn tcp_datagram_server(tx1: Sender<Value>) {
    let tx2 = tx1.clone();
    let mut buf = vec![0; 1024];
    info!("Waiting for client to connect...");
    if !buf.is_empty() {
        loop {
            socket.recv(&mut buf).expect("recv function failed");
            let received_message = from_utf8(&buf).expect("utf-8 convert failed");
            let closing_bracket_index = received_message.
                as_bytes().
                iter().
                position(|&binary_char_to_find| binary_char_to_find == b'}').
                map(|i| i + 1).
                unwrap_or_else(|| received_message.len());
            let message_json: Value = serde_json::from_str(&received_message[..closing_bracket_index]).unwrap();
            thread::spawn(move || tx1.send(message_json.clone()));
            thread::spawn(move || tx2.send(message_json.clone()));
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am receiving:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `tx1`
  --> src/example.rs:46:27
   |
23 | pub fn tcp_datagram_server(tx1: Sender<Value>) {
   |                            ---------------- move occurs because `tx1` has type `Sender<serde_json::Value>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
46 |             thread::spawn(move || tx1.send(message_json.clone()));
   |                           ^^^^^^^ ---------------- use occurs due to use in closure
   |                           |
   |                           value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `message_json`
  --> src/example.rs:47:27
   |
45 |             let message_json: Value = serde_json::from_str(&received_message[..closing_bracket_index]).unwrap();
   |                 ------------ move occurs because `message_json` has type `serde_json::Value`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
46 |             thread::spawn(move || tx1.send(message_json.clone()));
   |                           -------                       ------------ variable moved due to use in closure
   |                           |
   |                           value moved into closure here
47 |             thread::spawn(move || tx2.send(message_json.clone()));
   |                           ^^^^^^^         ------------ use occurs due to use in closure
   |                           |
   |                           value used here after move

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `tx2`
  --> src/unix_datagram_server.rs:47:27
   |
24 |     let tx2 = tx1.clone();
   |         -- move occurs because `tx2` has type `Sender<serde_json::Value>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait...
47 |             thread::spawn(move || tx2.send(message_json.clone()));
   |                           ^^^^^^^ -- use occurs due to use in closure
   |                           |
   |                           value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

Comment: You should first `clone` the message to create a second copy, then move both copies into their closure (without cloning them again). Here you're first *moving* the message into the closure then cloning it, so the closure owns two copies, sends one, and drops the other.

Comment: Though frankly I don't see the point of the threads here, the overhead of the threads is going to completely dwarf the send() cost, unless those are "rendezvous" channels which are almost certain to block.